# If my ManageMonster Class have bloated parser / input checker should I move it to a new class MngMonsterParser? (OOP design question)

Tags: ruby, oop, design-patterns

Say for example I have a microservice where I need a class where I can manage a monster from another service, like level it up, update its status (sick, hungry and etc) and take a picture with it(save picture somewhere local) through a terminal. The parsing part is located on the same class but I feel like I should have ManagerParser or ManageMonsterParser class...

```
class ManageMonster

  attr_accessor :monster_id, :status, :game_server...

  def initialize(cmd_args)
    #some intense parsing
    parse_args(cmd_args)
  end

  def update_status(monster_id, status)
    #call api to update status of monster
  end

  def level_up(monster_id)
    #level up the monster by 1
  end

  def take_picture(monster_id)
    #get monster coordinate, appearance
    #generate a picture with the data
  end

  def parse_args(cmd_args)
    #very long parsing code...
  end
end
```

I tried creating `ManageMonsterParser` class and pass the cmd_args there and just pass
its instance to the ManageMonster class. I am expecting a more cleaner more SRP code... I felt like parsing logic is not ManageMonster's responsibility.

Comment: Since you originally tagged Smalltalk, I encourage you to study PetitParser. This is the most object oriented parser I know of. https://scg.unibe.ch/research/helvetia/petitparser . The grammar is a class, and the rules are methods, written in a PEG-like syntax. And PetitParser implementation itself is a jool (a jewel in object oriented language), all grammar structures are reified. I don't know if there is an equivalent package in ruby though...

Comment: Also, read this http://objology.blogspot.com/2011/09/one-of-best-bits-of-programming-advice.html ... Parser is more an action reified (to parse) and manage absolutely a verb too... In PetitParser the object would be a Grammar, and you would delegate parsing to it (aGrammar parse: someString)

Comment: Thanks ! I will look into the article you shared !

Comment: @aka.nice The link with petitparser has images that doesn't load... but I read the objology.blogspot one... what I got from it was I shouldn't be creating Manager Class in the first place? instead I should have Monster class and focus in it? but I already have that on my other microservice...

Comment: you can try https://www.lukas-renggli.ch/blog/petitparser-1 and https://www.lukas-renggli.ch/blog/petitparser-2 or find other tutorials on the internet. I find it enlightening to study the implementation, and for that you need to explore source code... The main point of the other article is to focus on data and bind behavior to it. It generally works better (reusable components, smaller classes, etc...) than the other way around. Classes designed with with a behavior in mind (understand more procedural) require lots more states, instance variables, etc...

Comment: What are `cmd_args`? Are they actually command line arguments?

Comment: yes ! they are actually cmd line args I am currently parsing them with optparser library in ruby, but still my initializer handles what happens in each parsing statement.